# My first JS program - Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: javascript, beginner, css

I just completed some beginner web-dev courses (cs:50 and such) and wanted to try my skills.

The CSS centering - ugh I just gave up on that, I wanted to make it responsive and the letters centered perfectly, but whatever...

So overall, how is this coded? is there a better way to code this?

```js
let turn = true;
        let children;
        let winnerFound = false;

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load);

        function load() {
            children = document.getElementsByClassName("child");
            for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                children[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                    clicked(i);
                });
            }
            document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    clearBoard();
                }
            );
            updateTurn();
        }

        function clearBoard() {
            for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                children[i].innerHTML = '';
                children[i].classList.remove('animate');
            }
            turn = true;
            winnerFound = false;
            updateTurn();
        }

        //text at the top
        function updateTurn() {
            if (turn)
                document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = "X";
            else
                document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = "O";
        }

        function clicked(i) {
            if (winnerFound)
                return;
            if (children[i].childElementCount !== 0)
                return;
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            if (turn) {
                div.textContent = 'X';
            }
            else {
                div.textContent = 'O';
            }
            children[i].appendChild(div);
            children[i].classList.add('animate');
            turn = !turn;
            checkWinner();
            updateTurn();
        }

        function checkWinner() {
            //check rows
            for (let x = 0; x < 9; x += 3) {
                if (childContent(x) === childContent(x + 1) && childContent(x) === childContent(x + 2)) {
                    alert(childContent(x) + " won!");
                    winnerFound = true;
                }
            }
            //check columns
            for (let x = 0; x < 3; x += 1) {
                if (childContent(x) === childContent(x + 3) && childContent(x) === childContent(x + 6)) {
                    alert(childContent(x)+ " won!");
                    winnerFound = true;
                }
            }
            //check diagonals
            if (childContent(0) === childContent(4) && childContent(0) === childContent(8)) {
                alert(childContent(0)+ " won!");
                winnerFound = true;
            }
            if (childContent(2) === childContent(4) && childContent(2) === childContent(6)) {
                alert(childContent(2)+ " won!");
                winnerFound = true;
            }
        }

        function childContent(i) {
            if (children[i].childElementCount === 0) {
                return i;
            }
            return children[i].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML;
        }
```

```css
 body {
            background: lightgray;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .child:hover {
            background-color: darkgrey;
        }

        .parent {
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            width: 400px;
        }

        .child {
            flex: 1 0 calc(33% - 10px);
            margin: 5px;
            height: 80px;
            background-color: grey;
        }

        .animate {
            animation: changeColor 0.5s forwards;
        }

        @keyframes changeColor {
            0% {
                background-color: darkgrey;
            }
            100% {
                background-color: khaki;
                font-size: 60px;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <h2>It is now the turn of: <span id="turn"></span></h2>
    <button id="clear">CLEAR</button>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

## Review

Not bad for a beginner and welcome to the world of programing.

As you are new to coding I will just focus on one aspect of your code. The naming (which is very poor). There are many other things that I had to resist changing, but did not want to overwhelm you with the technicalities of client side Javascript, CSS, DOM, and markup.

### Naming

- Naming is very important, it gives meaning to code, data, and how it relates to the abstract concepts that make up a project. Bad naming will result in hard to read code, ambiguity and bugs.
- Good naming is not easy and takes time to learn by experience and example. (Read other peoples code and pay attention to how they name things).
- Good naming does not name what something is, but what it represents in the current context of the code.
- Good naming means you don't have to fill your code with comments to explain what can not be deduced from the code. Though you have done well in your comments :)

**Some specific name examples.**

You have the variable  `children`. Yes it is a list of children, that can be worked out by looking at how you declare its content, but in a bigger project there will be many children. The name does not represent what abstractly it holds, and that is board positions. If I ask `What are the positions in a game of Tic Tac Toe?`, you know what that means, as opposed to `What are the children in a game of Tic Tac Toe?` whaa! I have renamed `children` to `positions`

You have done the same in the CSS and markup. The classes `.child`, `.parent` `.animate` have no connection to the abstraction of Tic Tac Toe. Better name may be `.child` is `.position`, `.parent` is `.board`, `.animate` is `.playerMoved`

Most of the function names are good with the exception of `childContent` and `clicked`. Better names could be `childContent` as `getPositonContent` (as you use this function a lot in `checkWinner` a better name is `getPos` so that the code is not cluttered with a long name) and `clicked` as `playerMove`

### Refactoring your code.

The rewrite is mostly just renaming the many poor names you used. There are also a few minor code changes. BTW the names I picked may not be what you would have used to represent the various abstracts, they are just examples.

- `turnDisplay` created in load so you dont have to query the DOM each time.
- `playerMove` gets the position element rather than the index.
- The listener for clear is passed the function directly rather than use the indirect call `addEventListener("click", function() { clearBoard() })`
- Changed some `innerHTML` references to `textContent`

```js
let turn = true;
let positions, turnDisplay;
let winnerFound = false;


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load);

function load() {
  positions = document.getElementsByClassName("position");
  turnDisplay = document.getElementById("turnDisplay");
  for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    positions[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      playerMove(positions[i])
    });
  }
  document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", clearBoard);
  displayTurn();
}

function clearBoard() {
  for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    positions[i].innerHTML = '';
    positions[i].classList.remove('playerMoved');
  }
  turn = true;
  winnerFound = false;
  displayTurn();
}

function displayTurn() {
  if (turn) {
    turnDisplay.textContent = "X";
  } else {
    turnDisplay.textContent = "O";
  }
}

function playerMove(position) {
  if (winnerFound) {
    return
  }
  if (position.childElementCount !== 0) {
    return
  }
  const mark = document.createElement('div');
  if (turn) {
    mark.textContent = 'X'
  } else {
    mark.textContent = 'O'
  }
  position.appendChild(mark);
  position.classList.add('playerMoved');
  turn = !turn;
  checkWinner();
  displayTurn();
}

function checkWinner() {
  for (let x = 0; x < 9; x += 3) {
    if (getPos(x) === getPos(x + 1) && getPos(x) === getPos(x + 2)) {
      alert(getPos(x) + " won!");
      winnerFound = true;
    }
  }
  for (let x = 0; x < 3; x += 1) {
    if (getPos(x) === getPos(x + 3) && getPos(x) === getPos(x + 6)) {
      alert(getPos(x) + " won!");
      winnerFound = true;
    }
  }
  if (getPos(0) === getPos(4) && getPos(0) === getPos(8)) {
    alert(getPos(0) + " won!");
    winnerFound = true;
  }
  if (getPos(2) === getPos(4) && getPos(2) === getPos(6)) {
    alert(getPos(2) + " won!");
    winnerFound = true;
  }
}

function getPos(index) {
  if (positions[index].childElementCount === 0) {
    return index
  }
  return positions[index].textContent;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.position:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.board {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.position {
  flex: 1 0 calc(33% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.playerMoved {
  animation: changeColor 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    background-color: darkgrey;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: khaki;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
  <h2>It is now the turn of: <span id="turnDisplay"></span></h2>
  <button id="clear">CLEAR</button>
</div>
<div class="board">
  <div class="position"></div>
  <div class="position"></div>
  <div class="position"></div>
  <div class="position"></div>
  <div class="position"></div>
  <div class="position"></div>
  <div class="position"></div>
  <div class="position"></div>
  <div class="position"></div>
</div>
```

<sub><sup>**Note:** the above example is just concerned with naming, and does not represent an ideal code example. The idea was to keep as close to the OP's original code as possible.</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my code. Those are very useful tips. Going forward, I will learn some JS Framework (React or Vue I was thinking) so I won't have problems with updating the DOM.